# Allowing a group Read-Write Access to a directory

Tags: permissions

I have two users, user1 and user2, that are both members of groupA. user2 has a folder in their home directory called folderA. If they wish to allow read-write-execute permissions for all members of groupA, how would they do this?

What if folderA contains many files and additional folders that also need to have read-write-execute permission?

Information regarding groups is a little 'spotty' across the web, so I am putting my question here in the hope someone posts a clear answer that might help others out too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 124, accepted):

**FolderA** will first need to be part of **groupA** - the folder's owner or root can perform this operation

```
chgrp groupA ./folderA
```

Then **groupA** will need rwx permissions of the folder

```
chmod g+rwx  ./folderA
```

There are options in the `chgrp` and `chmod` commands to recurse into the directory if required.

Comment: note: you should make sure that you can access *intermediate* directories too (+x might be enough).

Comment: I originally tried `chown :groupname ./folder` and that didnt work - as in it changed the group, but didn't give any effective permissions

Comment: didn't worked for me also. Folder somehow can not give write permissions to a group. Whatever I have tried.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @ScottF Can you list the properties of the directory with `ls -l ./folderA` to ensure that the group permissions were applied?

Comment: I followed these commands verbatim on Ubuntu 18.04.6 and on any member of the group, within the directory, on `touch test.txt`, I get the error: `touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Permission denied` . I'm trying to give access to the group `appowners`. This is the output of `ls -al` : `drwxrwxr-x  2 root appowners  4096 Apr 18 22:38 src` . EDIT: The reason was, if a user is added to a new group, they must re-login to receive the new group permissions.

Comment: User and group permission changes do not take effect until you logout and login again (see [answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098707/29073)), you might even need to reboot if a folder is held open by a user having access on logout. At least IME, with much frustration, changes do not take place when you do chown/chgrp/chmod but only (loosely speaking) on reboot. Sometimes it might be enough to start a new shell, or new TTY, but a reboot definitely works.

Comment: @pbhj  That has not been my experience, although I will admit to not having great depth of experience.  I do need to logout/in if I have altered the user or group - the login does not pickup altered permissions until the next login.  But altered file and directory permissions work immediately for me.

Answer (score 15):

My own experience in this area here. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

#### Allow to write in the system folder

Give write permission to `/etc/nginx/` folder.

```sh
# Check 'webmasters' group doen't exist
cat /etc/group | grep webmasters
# Create 'webmasters' group
sudo addgroup webmasters
# Add users to 'webmasters' group
sudo usermod -a -G webmasters username
sudo usermod -a -G webmasters vozman
sudo usermod -a -G webmasters romanroskach

# Group assignment changes won't take effect
# until the users log out and back in.

# Create directory
sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/
# Check directory permissions
ls -al /etc | grep nginx
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Dec  5 18:30 nginx

# Change group owner of the directory
sudo chgrp -R webmasters /etc/nginx/
# Check that the group owner is changed
ls -al /etc | grep nginx
drwxr-xr-x   2 root webmasters   4096 Dec  5 18:30 nginx

# Give write permission to the group
sudo chmod -R g+w /etc/nginx/
# Check
ls -al /etc | grep nginx
drwxrwxr-x   2 root webmasters   4096 Dec  5 18:30 nginx

# Try to create file
sudo -u username touch /etc/nginx/test.txt  # should work
sudo -u username touch /etc/test.txt  # Permission denied
```

Give write permission to `/etc/systemd/system/` folder.

```sh
# List ACLs
getfacl /etc/systemd/system

getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: etc/systemd/system
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

# Add 'webmasters' group to an ACL
sudo setfacl -m g:webmasters:rwx /etc/systemd/system

# Check
getfacl /etc/systemd/system

getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: etc/systemd/system
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:webmasters:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x

sudo -u username touch /etc/systemd/system/test.txt  # should work
sudo -u username touch /etc/systemd/test.txt  # Permission denied
```

[Original how-to](https://github.com/foobar167/articles/blob/master/Ubuntu/07_Website_software.md/#allow-write).

Comment: Works great! Thank You!

Comment: Do you use php-fpm with that workflow? With which user? www-data or webmasters