# change permissions of folder to group sudo read/write and all users only read

Tags: command-line, permissions

How can i change the permissions of directory `public` to all users only read and only `sudo` users (group members of `sudo`) to only read/write access.

I prefer to do it like this :

```
chown root:sudo ~/public
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowing a group Read-Write Access to a directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488485/allowing-a-group-read-write-access-to-a-directory)

Comment: its not a duplicate if you read the question right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) and [chgrp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chgrp) are the tools needed here:

```
# make the group 'sudo' the owner of the directory 'public'
chgrp sudo public   

# give the group read/write access and others just read access
chmod g=rwx,o=rx public
```

Result:

```
ls -ld public
drwxrwxr-x 2 pduck sudo 4096 Feb  4 14:08 public
```

---

#### Update

If you also want to prevent the current owner `pduck` from accessing the directory (regardless of his membership), then give the ownership to `root`:

```
sudo chown root:sudo public
sudo chmod 0750 public

# result:
drwxrwxr-x 2 root sudo 4096 Feb 28 11:32 public
```

Now only `root` and members of the `sudo` group have read/write access. But `root` can access the directory anyway, even when he's not the owner, so **this is safe**.

---

The first thought might be to keep the ownership and just reduce the rights:

```
sudo chown pduck:sudo public
sudo chmod 0050 public

# gives
d---r-x--- 2 pduck sudo 4096 Feb 28 11:32 public
```

Now – although the owner – `pduck` cannot access the directory. But (as owner) he can simply regain access by issuing `chmod u+rwx public` himself, so **this is not safe**.

Comment: What if pduck is not in group sudo ?

Comment: @An0n Because there is `rwx` in the owner bits and he is the owner, he has full access – regardless of his group membership. I updated my post to explain how to circumvent that.